# Reshaping Numpy arrays

Tags: keras, numpy, python-3.x

I am having a problem trying to reshape my numpy array. i have a 2 dimensional array and i want to make it a 3D array. I have looked everywhere but even if i find some answering my question they just make it complicated. I just want to know is there a mathematical way to calculate reshaping a numpy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand what you mean, but `numpy.expand_dims` can be used to expand an array at the given index, allowing you to convert a 2 dimensional array to a 3 dimensional array.

```py
import numpy as np

array = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
print(array.shape)
# (2, 2)
array = np.expand_dims(array, 0)
print(array.shape)
# (1, 2, 2)
```

Comment: I managed to solve it, let me just answer my own question .

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem, so let me explain it so it all makes sense. So I had a 2D array of shape (76, 5) right,  and I wanted to reshape it to a 3D (76, 2, 5) array so i can stick it in to my keras LSTM model. But this is how I was doing it `np.reshape(array, (76, 2, 5))`, and this gave me the error that looked something like this **cannot reshape array of size 380 to array of shape (76, 2, 5)**. So my confusion lied in the relationship between dimension and size. I than figured out that you could get the size from just knowing the dimension (if you multiply your dimensions you get your size), therefore 76*5 = 380 which is the size and 76*2*5 = 760 which is too big to fit in my old array. In order to reshape my array to become 3D I had to adjust some values

```
row = int(array.shape[0]/2) #The additional dimension i want to add
array = np.reshape(array, (row, 2, 5))
```

So now the shape of my array is (38, 2, 5) and the resulting size is now 38*2*5 = 380. So in conclusion if you want to reshape an already existing array, find the size first using the

```
array.size
```

Than make sure that the multiplication of the dimensions of the new array that you want is equivalent to the size.